# Drop down menu to start function

Tags: python, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, tkinter

Below is the code to a drop down menu. I would like functions to be performed depending on what is selected. How would I do this. Is there a piece of code that reads the selection and if a certain thing selected it performs the desired function.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time

def menu():

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Menu")

    menu = Frame(root)
    menu.pack(pady = 5, padx = 50)
    var = StringVar(root)

def printgender():
    print("q")

    options = [
        'Unique ID number', 
        'Surname',
        'Forename',
        'Date of birth',
        'Home address',
        'Home phone number',
        'Gender',
        'Tutor group',
        'Email address',
    ]
    option = OptionMenu(menu, var, options[0], *options)

    var.set('Select')

    option.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the action to occur after selecting an `option`from the `OptionMenu` then this can be achieved by setting a `command` for the `OptionMenu`, see my code example below for a demonstation:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command(*args):
    print(var.get())

var = StringVar()
var.set("one")

option = OptionMenu(root, var, "one", "two", "three", command=command)

option.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Alternatively, you could also do this with a button, as seen below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command(*args):
    print(var.get())

var = StringVar()
var.set("one")

option = OptionMenu(root, var, "one", "two", "three")
button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=command)

option.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```